# Create a new column based in If Statments R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I would like to know if I can create if statements based in characters. such is

this is not a real code I am trying to understand if this is possible

```
if {taskStaffName != 'Carl Goss' add 80
else{ if taskStaffName = 'Carl Goss' add 40}
```

else{ if taskStaffName = 'Ama Fh' add 44}

Data Sample:

```
    taskStaffName false true
1      Ama Fh      11    0
2      Bar Mi      14   88
3     Briny Rey     6    0
4       Ben Le     20   65
5      Co Wams    165  398
6  Don Chrensen     7  106
7    Da Cari        0    5
8    Geth by        9  546
9  Hen Vaeghem     34  157
10   Jemy Haran     2   35
11      Joph Le     9   22
12    Carl Goss    69  360
```

Outcome Desired:

```
    taskStaffName false true  Budget
1      Ama Fh      11    0     44
2      Bar Mi      14   88     80
3     Briny Rey     6    0     80
4       Ben Le     20   65     80
5      Co Wams    165  398     80
6  Don Chrensen     7  106     80
7    Da Cari        0    5     80
8    Geth by        9  546     80
9  Hen Vaeghem     34  157     80
10   Jemy Haran     2   35     80
11      Joph Le     9   22     80
12    Carl Goss    69  360     40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can try using `ifelse` here:

```
df$Budget <- ifelse(df$taskStaffName == "Carl Goss", 40, 80)
```

Assuming you actually wanted to add a value to the budget column, then use:

```
df$Budget <- df$Budget + ifelse(df$taskStaffName == "Carl Goss", 40, 80)
```

To handle more than two uses cases, we can try using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
df$Budget <- case_when(
    df$taskStaffName == "Carl Goss" ~ 40,
    df$taskStaffName == "Ama Fh" ~ 44,
    TRUE ~ 80
)
```

The way of doing this in base R would be to just nest calls to `ifelse`, but this quickly becomes unreadable.

Comment: What would you do if they are 2 that are differents  Ama Fh      11    0     44, Carl Goss    69  360     40 and the rest 80, sorry I just edited my post. 
Thanks by the way

Comment: Error: unexpected '=' in "Exp$Budget <- Exp$Budget + ifelse(Exp$taskStaffName ="

Comment: Sorry, I keep doing this.  You need to use `==` as the equality operator.  Keep in mind that much of the code posted to Stack Overflow hasn't (and sometimes can't be) tested.